# notation for index of integers in some range

Tags: notation

If I have an expression like
$$
\mu^i(x,t) = 0 \qquad, \qquad \qquad i=1,\dots, K
$$

I want a more compact way of specifying that the index $i$ takes integer values from $1$ to $K$.  I'm looking for something  like $i\in I_1^K$, or $i\in \mathbb{Z}_1^K$, etc. Is there a standard notation for this that I have missed? Something like $i\in [1,K]$ does not work as it does not make clear that $i$ is an integer.

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard notation for this aside from the "less compact" one you give above

Comment: Some people use $[K]$ as notation for the set $\{1,\dots,K\}$. (but also sometimes $\{0,\dots,K\}$ or $\{0,\dots,K-1\}$) But frame challenge: the goal of mathematical writing is clarity, not compactness—and $i=1,\dots,K$ is extremely clear as well as quite compact.

Comment: @GregMartin yes that is true and in my example there would be no need for more compact, perhaps less clear, notation. But I often have work with lots of indices ranging over different numbers and specifying each as $i=1,\dots, K$ quickly gets cumbersome and equations are cluttered with index ranges. Just using $i\in[K]$, $\alpha\in[N]$, etc. as you mentioned would be nice.

Comment: if @GregMartin 's suggestion suits you, define $[k]$ and use it. +1 for the frame challenge in his comment.